# Fish scale type pattern using blend and custom brush tool

Tags: adobe-illustrator, blending

I'm trying follow [this](http://www.digitalartsonline.co.uk/tutorials/adobe-illustrator/design-for-vinyl-wall-stickers/#8) tutorial to create the leaf pattern.(Scroll down to see step 7. SO won't allow me to post more than 2 links).

I created the lines using blend tool, and created the brush and applied it on the lines as instructed. But I'm not sure what the artist means by "you may need to make the lines into overlapping solid objects to fill spaces.". I'm stuck and don't know how to make that image. All I can get to is the following (ignore the red bug). Any help on how to proceed will be helpful:

[image]

I'm using Adobe-illustrator CC.

Comment: you made the first row with lemon green, you should repeat it underneath the darker green, or just blend the rows with each others.

Answer (score 1):

It's a terminology issue:

> You may need to make *the lines* `(the paths)` into overlapping *solid objects* `(shapes)` to fill spaces

Use the **Pen Tool** to convert the open paths into shapes and fill them with the same color as the stroke.

[image: Path to shape]